# Creating two color linear gradient .ppm files in C++

Tags: c++, gradient, ppm

For a school assignment I need to create a `.ppm` file that is a gradient from one color to another using C++. I also have to define the number of columns and rows the `.ppm` file has. I don't know how to mathematically create the gradient color. Could someone help with the mathematics and code to achieve this?

So far I've been able to output the color, I just don't know how to make it gradient.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct Color{
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
};

void Grad(int rows, int cols, Color c1, Color c2, string filename);

void Grad(int rows, int cols, Color c1, Color c2, string filename){
    ofstream out(filename + ".ppm");

    int y;
    int x;

    out << "P6\n"
        << cols << " " << rows << "\n"
        << "255\n";

    for (y = 0; y < rows; y++){

        for (x = 0; x < cols; x++) {

            unsigned char r,g,b;

            r = (c1.r + ((x / 255) * (c2.r - c1.r)));
            g = (c1.g + ((x / 255) * (c2.g - c1.g)));
            b = (c1.b + ((x / 255) * (c2.b - c1.b)));

            out << r << g << b;

        }

    }
}

int main(){
    string bw = "blackToWhite";
    string ry = "redToYellow";
    string fb = "fooToBar";

    Color black; black.r=0; black.g=0; black.b=0;
    Color white; white.r=255; white.g=255; white.b=255;
    Color red; red.r=255; red.g=0; red.b=0;
    Color yellow; yellow.r=255; yellow.g=255; yellow.b=0;
    Color foo; foo.r=21; foo.g=156; foo.b=221;
    Color bar; bar.r=253; bar.g=24; bar.b=129;

    Grad(64,256,black,white,bw);
    Grad(400,2000,red,yellow,ry);
    Grad(234,800,foo,bar,fb);

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with the code as presented, is that it uses *integer arithmetic*. That way e.g. `x / 255` yields 0 for every `x` value less than 255. This calculation should be done in floating point (preferably type `double`, which is the default), which you can do simply by writing `x / 255.0`, and then with the final result converted to integer.

That way, with reliable calculations, you'll more easily spot other problems.

Hopefully. ;-)

Comment: Thanks! That helped out a little. I think I can figure out the rest of the problems I'm having with it haha